# How to access referenced object from RPC client in corda?

Tags: corda

In the flow of creating some state I add reference state to some other object (some custom account in my case). So when I receive this state on the rpc client by trackBy() method I want to know what object it referencing.
  As I understand, reference exists in transaction, not in the state. What is the proper way to get transaction from state in RPC client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure you can do that directly from the client, you'd probably need to write a flow that accepts a transaction Id and returns a list of the references.
So inside your flow you'd have something like:

```
SignedTransaction tx = this.getServiceHub().getValidatedTransactions()
                           .getTransaction(SecureHash.parse("Your Tx Id"));
ArrayList<StateRef> refs = tx.getReferences();
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, Adel. So I need to call some technical flow from RPC client to get references from my state? Seems to be easier to add reference to my state and check consistency in the contract. In this case I will be able to get referenced object from the state and may be pretty sure that this is what is in transaction's references.

Comment: There is difference between the 2 scenarios that you mentioned in your comment.

Comment: **Reference states:** Are added to a transaction so that they can be accessed inside the contract and used in validation rules.  
https://docs.corda.net/design/reference-states/design.html

Comment: **StatePointer:** Is basically a pointer to a state, so you can have a state with an attribute which is a pointer to another state (it can be a StaticPointer or a LinearPointer).  Read here: https://docs.corda.r3.com/design/linear-pointer/design.html

Comment: Very usefull links, thanks! It seems for me that reference states needed for the sake of consistency on the consensus layer (notary validates that reference pointing to actual state etc.) and StateRef for utility purpose (what I realy needed).